# appending node to link list (I am almost there) in C

Tags: c, linked-list, append

I am trying to figure out how to append a node to the link list.
I feel like I am almost there but after staring at the code for a while now I cant think of whats wrong with it.

I have to mention that after adding first int to the list I get segmentation fault...

```
typedef struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node* next;    
}
node;

node* head;

void append(node* pHead, int data)
{
    node* current = pHead;
    node* newNode = NULL;
    newNode = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    newNode->data = data;
    newNode->next = NULL;

    if (current == NULL)
        pHead = newNode;    
    else
    {
        while (current->next != NULL)
            current = current->next;
    }
    current->next = newNode;       
}

int main(void)
{
    head = NULL;
    int howMany;
    int num;

    printf("how many?");
    scanf("%d", &howMany);

    for (int i = 0; i < howMany; i++)
    {
        printf("** %d ** number: ", i+1);
        scanf("%d", &num);
        append(head, num);
    }
```

Where is my error?

Comment: "_Where is my error?_" -- You are missing a `}` at the end of `main`.

Comment: I think that the problem is in the append() function :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is here:

```
if (current == NULL)
    pHead = newNode;    
else
{
    while (current->next != NULL)
        current = current->next;
}
current->next = newNode;
```

That last line, `current->next = newNode`, should be inside the `else` body, otherwise you will try to dereference a NULL pointer when `current` is NULL.

So, it should be:

```
if (current == NULL)
    pHead = newNode;    
else
{
    while (current->next != NULL)
        current = current->next;
    current->next = newNode;
}
```

Another problem is that you never modify `head`. You only modify the private, local copy of the head pointer inside `append()`. This modification is not visible outside of `append()`, so the program ends up leaking memory and you can never access the list (because `head` is always NULL). You can either make `pHead` a `node **` (so that modifications to `*pHead` are visible), or instead you can modify `head` inside `append()`, instead of passing it as an argument. This will work because you won't be modifying a private local copy. Here's how `append()` should look like:

```
void append(int data)
{
    node* current = head;
    node* newNode = NULL;
    newNode = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    newNode->data = data;
    newNode->next = NULL;

    if (current == NULL)
        head = newNode;
    else
    {
        while (current->next != NULL)
            current = current->next;
        current->next = newNode;
    }
}
```

Comment: @bartaspol Ah yeah, good point. It has to do with the way you manipulate `pHead`. See my updated answer.

Comment: I posted my second question and immediately saw your answer.
Thank you very much! I was going crazy with this :D

Answer (score 1):

You do `current->next = newNode;` even if current is NULL.

You must return from function when `(current == NULL)`:

```
if (current == NULL) {
    pHead = newNode;
    return;
}

else
{
    while (current->next != NULL)
        current = current->next;
}
current->next = newNode;
```

or put `current->next = newNode;` in else statement:

```
if (current == NULL) {
    pHead = newNode;
}

else
{
    while (current->next != NULL)
        current = current->next;
    current->next = newNode;
}
```

Full example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node* next;
}
node;

node* head;

void append(node* pHead, int data)
{
    node* current = pHead;
    node* newNode = NULL;
    newNode = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    newNode->data = data;
    newNode->next = NULL;

    if (current == NULL) {
        pHead = newNode;
        return;
    }

    else
    {
        while (current->next != NULL)
            current = current->next;
    }
    current->next = newNode;
}

int main(void)
{
    head = NULL;
    int howMany;
    int num;

    printf("how many?");
    scanf("%d", &howMany);

    for (int i = 0; i < howMany; i++)
    {
        printf("** %d ** number: ", i + 1);
        scanf("%d", &num);
        append(head, num);
    }
}
```